# Submitting Form Details using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am fairly new to PHP. I have to send the form details to mail id. I browsed through The Internet and get the various link about the same. But I am facing the similar situation that when I am submitting my form filled with details then it is downloading the PHP file in the browser and main thing is I am not getting mail.

Here I pasting my code-

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="page-wrapper">
<h1>AJAX Contact Form Demo</h1>
<div id="form-messages"></div>

<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The mailer.php

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // 
        $recipient = "shubhamvashishtha22@gmail.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

My app.js file

```
$(function() {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // TODO: The rest of the code will go here...
});


// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // TODO
});

// Serialize the form data.
var formData = $(form).serialize();


// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData
})
.done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);

            // Clear the form.
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');
        })

.fail(function(data) {
    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    $(formMessages).addClass('error');

    // Set the message text.
    if (data.responseText !== '') {
        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    } else {
        $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
    }
});
```

Can anyone please suggest me how I can make this problem go. I am actually just copying it than also this is happening. Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your server doesn't have a `SMTP` like`sendmail` or `postfix` enabled. You can run `phpinfo()` and look for this directive `sendmail_path` and see what is set.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the PHP file is downloaded through the browser. **This is not supposed to happen.** When the server gets a request for a PHP file, it is meant to run the PHP code and only respond with the resulting HTML page. Visitors to your web page should never see any code, only the text and tags you choose to echo, which leads me to believe that **your server may not actually be running PHP at the moment.**

**Is your PHP installation configured correctly, and is it running?** If you are not configuring your own server, does your web host of choice have PHP listed as one of the languages it supports?

Your AJAX doesn't seem to do anything other than telling the form to submit, so I don't think it's the problem, but for the sake of isolating the issue: What happens if you comment out the jQuery and AJAX script tags and just use a regular HTML form to POST to mailer.php?